# Application exit with code -8 before even tries to divide by 0?

Tags: c, exit, exit-code, divide-by-zero

I have code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t result = 0;
    uint8_t a = 0;
    printf("Trying to divide by %d...\n", a);
    result = (1/a != 0);
    printf("%d\n", result);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried this in **online compiler** here: https://www.mycompiler.io/new/c

And this is the result:

> [Execution complete with exit code -8]

I expected "Trying to divide by 0..." to be printed out, and then application should exit.

But the application exits before it prints anything.

Is it normal C behavior or some glitch of online compiler?

Comment: Division by zero leads to *undefined behavior*. Anything could happen, from a crash to your dog catching fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two possible explanations here

First, it's important to know that undefined behavior can time travel back in time. There is no guarantee that the program will run fine until the problematic line. This may occur because the compiler might think that it would be better to reorder things like this:

```
uint8_t a = 0;
uint8_t result = (1/a != 0);
printf("Trying to divide by %d...\n", a);
```

The compiler is allowed to do this, because it's allowed to assume that division by zero will never happen.

Second, it could be the case that the output needs to be flushed. Whenever you want to make sure that a printout gets visible on screen before doing something else, use `fflush(stdout)`. It might make a difference if you do this:

```
printf("Trying to divide by %d...\n", a);
fflush(stdout);
result = (1/a != 0);
```

Comment: Yes, this is it. I forgot again, that printf/console is pretty slow and printing functions behave like asynchronous because there is a buffer :) Thank you.

Comment: The output to the terminal would be line buffered or unbuffered. Adding `fflush` should not change anything.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Does the standard force the output to be one of those two options?

Comment: @EricPostpischil But it did...

Comment: @klutt: C 2018 7.21.3 7: “As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.”

Comment: @Kamil: Did adding `fflush(stdout)` **alone** change the behavior, or did other changes to the code change the behavior? Note that using an online compiler does not test behavior with a terminal, as an online compiler likely directs standard output to a file or pipe that it uses to capture the output.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Just `fflush(stdout)` changed it. But maybe this is due to online compiler that may have some extra buffers between streams and web application. You can try it here https://www.mycompiler.io/view/JF8a0LEq6YT and uncomment `fflush` line.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It says "fully buffered" and not "line buffered", right?

Comment: @klutt: It says fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined **not** to refer to an interactive device. That means, if the stream is determined to refer to a terminal or cannot be figured out, then the stream is not fully buffered. So it must be line buffered or unbuffered.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but as you said, the output here might be redirected so that it is fully buffered.